# Is there any way we can specify the node name during the knife bootstrap process??

Tags: chef-infra

Am using hosted chef and i want to bootstrap linux/windows node with explicitly mentioning the node name, rather than the default hostname,How can i do that?

Comment: Please consider marking an answer as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knife supports a **node-name** option. See the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html).

Example:

```
knife bootstrap myhost.mydomain.com \
  --node-name server1 \
  --ssh-user myuser \
  --sudo \
  --run-list "role[mymachines]"
```

Comment: the link does not open.

Comment: @anshupitlia Link updated